# Conditional probability distributions of two random variables as functions

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

" Consider 2 random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$:

- $X_1 = Y_1 \sqrt{\alpha + \beta {X_0}^2}$
- $X_2 = Y_2 \sqrt{\alpha + \beta {X_1}^2}$

$ \alpha>0 $ , $\beta \ge 0$

where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and both follow a normal standard distribution $N (0, 1)$. Also, $Y_1$ is independent of $X_0$ and $Y_2$ is independent of $X_1$.

Find the conditional probability distributions of $X_1|X_0 = x_0$ and $X_2|X_1 = x_1$. "

I'm guessing it has to do with the normal joint density but I don't know where to start since no information was given about $X_0$. Is it possible that $f(y_1) = f(x_1,x_0)$ and $f(y_2) = f(x_1,x_2)$ which would led to a bivariate normal joint density?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If we condition on $X_0 = x_0$, then the $\sqrt{\alpha + \beta X_0^2}$ term is essentially constant. If $Y_1 \sim N(0, 1)$, what is the distribution of $\sigma Y_1$ for $\sigma > 0$?

Comment: Ah yes $X_1|X_0 = x_0$ ∼ $N(0, \alpha + \beta {x_0}^2)$ and $X_2|X_1 = x_1$ ∼ $N(0,\alpha + \beta {x_1}^2)$ !
Thank you so much!